# Getting type information after using offsetof macro

Tags: c, pointers

I'm goofing around with using `offsetof()` macro and I'm just trying to understand what additional steps I need to take to obtain the correct data type when working with said offset.

In this *mostly not pseudocode* example:

```
typedef struct {
    double a;
    float b;
    int c;
    short d;
} MyStruct;

void doStuff(MyStruct* myStruct) {
    char* base = (char*)myStruct;
    int offsetA = offsetof(MyStruct, a);
    int offsetB = offsetof(MyStruct, b);
    int offsetC = offsetof(MyStruct, c);
    int offsetD = offsetof(MyStruct, d);

    double d = *(double*)(base+offsetA) + *(float*)(base+offsetB) + *(int*)(base+offsetC) + *(short*)(base+offsetD);
}
```

Notice I need to cast the offset to the specific data type as defined in `MyStruct`.

Is there any way I can further genericize this calculation so I don't need to know the type information ahead of time?

**EDIT**

Folks, I appreciate the comments, but I'm primarily focusing on `offsetof()` macro from an educational standpoint.  I understand that I can do simple pointer dereferencing to get the values.  But if all I have are offsets to a pointer, how can I get type information to make knowing the offsets useful?

Comment: Note: the return type of `offsetof()` is `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: Have you researched `_Generic`?  The type information of the members is not in the return value of `offsetof()`.

Comment: what's wrong with `double d = myStruct->a + myStruct->b + myStruct->c + myStruct->d;` ?

Comment: If you're using GCC, you could try their `typeof` operator: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html.

Comment: If all you have is the offset, all you have is the offset. C does not store type information, and neither does the RAM; a `1`  bit in a float is the same colour as a `1` bit in an integer.